# KnockoutJS getting from selection screen to edit / add screen

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am just starting to learn KnockoutJS so forgive me if this question seems silly but using an ASP MVC 3 framework how do I get information from my selection screen into my add / edit view.

Basically I have used MVCScaffold to build a basic controller for each model I have which contains an Index, Create, Edit, _CreateEdit and a couple other views.  This works fine when using models because the controller creates them and passes them into my view, but now I am trying to use Knockout so I thought I was not supposed to pass a model but once in the view use a $get to grab data from the server to show on the view. That being said once I get to my edit / add screen from my selection view how do I know what record to grab using the $get function.  Am I still supposed to pass some information into the model?  It seems like there must be a better way than that.  I am just not sure of the best practice.

Also I have an Add and Edit screen but both use the partial view of _CreateEdit so if I make my view model in the Create or Edit view how do I access this or pass it to my partial views?

Comment: I am sure there are a ton of ways to accomplish this but I am tryign to find the best practice for this sort of thing to follow in the future

Answer (score 0):

Depends, are you trying to use [`Razor`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_ASP.NET_Razor_view_engine) with `Knockout`? If so then you are in a hybrid situation where some things might come from the `Razor` - Model and some might come from ajax calls.

I'm guessing your `$get` is supposed to be [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/). Which we would call an [`Ajax`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) call

If on the other hand you want to go more pure `Knockout` then you would probably use a [`WebAPI Controller`](http://www.asp.net/web-api) instead.

If you want to return a model from your mvc `Controller` that `Knockout` could read easily then do this:

```
if (this.Request.IsAjaxRequest()) return Json(model,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```